# How to show build directory in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: build, intellij-idea, gradle

I build my project and on the file system I see the build directory but in IntelliJ IDEA 13.01 I see:
[image]

How to make IntelliJ to show it like in Eclipse

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe your build directory is marked as "Excluded". Go to Project Settings -> Modules -> your module. Remove "Excluded" mark from your build directory.

[image]

Then modules->

[image]

Comment: Also make sure that Show Excluded Folders is checked. It is under the Gear context menu in the Project view.

Comment: adding to above answer..
go to Settings -> Build, execution, development -> Build tools -> Maven -> importing -> check if 'Exclude  build directory' checkbox is checked -> uncheck it

Answer (score 2):

You could overwrite the exclude of the `build` directory (see [IdeaModule](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html) in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html) for details). However, from what I remember, this will slow down IntelliJ, give duplicates in file searches, etc. Hence, it may not be a good solution to whatever problem you are ultimately trying to solve.

Comment: I just want to see build dir in IDEA IDE and to see if every thing with my build is ok.